# Agda Type-Checking Error

Tags: typechecking, operation, agda

I'm currently making an ordered vector datatype and I'm trying to create operations from the data type but I get an error:

```
(Set (.Agda.Primitive.lsuc ℓ)) != Set
when checking that the expression A has type Set ℓ
```

This is the datatype

```
module ordered-vector (A : Set) (_<A_ : A → A → ) where

data ordered- : {A : Set}→ A  →  ℕ → Set where
      [] : {a : A} →  ordered- a 0
      _::_  : (head : A) {min : A} → {n : ℕ} → (tail : ordered- min n) → true (min <A head) → ordered- head (suc n)
```

And this is the operation:

```
[_]o : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} →  A  →   ordered- A 1
[ x ]o = x :: []
```

I believe the following code is more correct for the datatype. How do I retain the correctness of the cons part of the definition?

```
data ordered- {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : ℕ →  Set ℓ where
  [] :  ordered- A 0
  _::_  : (head : A) {min : A} → {n : ℕ} →  ordered- min n → true (min <A head) → ordered- head (suc n)
```

This is the nat module

http://lpaste.net/147233

Comment: Oops yeah that was an error. I fixed it's supposed to be  ordered-

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the type of `[_]o` doesn't make much sense, because you are passing the **type** of the argument (the type of `x`) as the index to `ordered-`; I believe you are trying to do

```
[_]o : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} → (a : A) → ordered- a 1
```

instead.

If you change the type of `[_]o` accordingly, you will still get the error message

```
(Set ℓ) != Set 
when checking that the expression a has type A
```

and that is because your definition of `[_]o` tries to be level-polymorphic, but your definition of `ordered-` isn't.

You can either make `[_]o` "dumber":

```
[_]o : ∀ {A : Set} → (a : A) → ordered a 1
[ x ]o = x ∷ []
```

or make `ordered-` "smarter":

```
data ordered- {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} : A → ℕ → Set ℓ where
  [] : {a : A} →  ordered- a 0
  _∷_  : (head : A) {min : A} → {n : ℕ} → (tail : ordered- min n) → true (min <A head) → ordered- head (suc n)
```

However, if you want `A` and `_<A_` to be parameters to your module, I think this is altogether the wrong approach, and `ordered-` should simply not be parametric in the choice of `A` at all:

```
module ordered-vector (A : Set) (_<A_ : A → A → ) where
  data ordered- : A → ℕ → Set where
    [] : {a : A} →  ordered- a 0
    _∷_  : (head : A) {min : A} → {n : ℕ} → (tail : ordered- min n) → true (min <A head) → ordered- head (suc n)
```

Comment: I see, I included some more information my file, namely `(_<A_ : A → A → )` 
and I believe that's also causing problems with my datatype. Is that a problem with the true() operation or elsewhere?

Comment: I wish I could understand any of these.

Comment: @SharkMangler Where is that `true` defined, anyway? It certainly can't be the `Bool` constructor from `Data.Bool`... maybe you meant `T`? Do you have a full version that actually typechecks if you comment out the definition of `[_]o`?

Comment: @PauloTorrens feel free to post followup questions (as new questions)!

Comment: what would making A not a parametric choice affect the [_]o operation?

Comment: the true operation is a bool-to-Set operation to quickly fix an error I was getting while defining the property of the ordered vector. 

`true :  → Set
true tt = truth
true ff = absurd`

Comment: If you bind `A` on the module level, that means it will be the same `A` everywhere inside the module, so you can't choose something else for `A` in `[_]o`. For intuition, you can also think about where the definition of `_<A_` would come if `[_]o` was allowed to change the choice of `A`...

Comment: @SharkMangler that `true` is available in the standard library as `Data.Bool.T` FYI. Also, aren't you going to need more from `_<A_` than just a random binary boolean function? Where do you plan to get that `true (min <A head)` argument to ` _::_` from?

Comment: Shouldn't simply changing the `A` to something like `B` in the definition of `[_]o` fix it? Thanks for the help. Agda is very hard to grasp!

Comment: I'm not using the standard library for my class. There was no such module. I believe for my class that they are only testing with natural numbers but I have to provide a ordered vector for all sets as it's out of my current scope for such things.

Comment: So, either you have the definition of `ordered-` parametric in the choice of `A` **and** `_<A_`, or you need to fix those (but that "fixing" can come from a higher-level parameter, in your case, the module parameter).

Comment: @SharkMangler if you are not using the standard library, then this question is ripe for closing as "off-topic because it doesn't contain all necessary code" since you never defined `ℕ`...

Comment: Would providing definition of `ℕ` help? New to the rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: The ideal version of your question would be one where you have all the code needed that typechecks on its own, and then you have the definition of the single function with which you have problems. I was filling in the blanks by assuming your `ℕ` is the one from `Data.Nat` and by, frankly, ignoring the `true` stuff because that was the only way to make progress.